# Altium - Deselect after compile error

Tags: altium

When I compile my schematic, I get some errors in the compile window. When I double click them it zooms in on them and highlights them with a mask. How do I get rid of that mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "Clear" button at the bottom right of the editor window.

[image]